# Save image from gallery

Tags: android, image, gallery

I can't save the image selected from the gallery by the same principle

```
@SuppressLint("QueryPermissionsNeeded")
public void createPhoto() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createPhotoFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity,
                    "com.example.notes.android.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            activity.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }
    }
}

public File createPhotoFile() throws IOException {
    File image = File.createTempFile(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()), ".jpg", storageDir);
    setPhotoPath(image.getAbsolutePath());
    return image;
}
```

How can I do the same with the selected image?

```
@SuppressLint("QueryPermissionsNeeded")
public void createImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_IMAGE);
    }
}
```

Although the selected images appear in the file, they are not readable

Comment: Which principle? And ACTION_GET_CONTENT gives you an urie to an image. What is it that you wanna do then?

Comment: With the link to the image from the gallery I want to copy the image to my created folder, then get the link of the copied image and save to the database.

Comment: `With the link to the image from the gallery` You mean: `with the uri obtained with ACTION_GET_CONTENT`.  Well what is the problem doing so? And why first make a copy? You could store the first uri too.

Comment: Yes, everything is correct, I can save the first link, but if I delete the original image, the link will not be relevant. Therefore, a copy is needed that will not be displayed in the gallery.